# cURL error 60 is going while using google auth api

Tags: laravel, curl, google-authentication

> GuzzleHttp \ Exception \ RequestException
>   cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
>    (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

I'm using google+ api and this error is not going even after adding `cacert.php` and modifying `php.ini`

```
curl.cainfo = "‪C:\xampp\php\extras\ssl\cacert.pem"
```

xampp server
windows

Comment: what about disabling SSL check ?

Comment: @FarazIrfan how and from where i can disable this?