# WooCommce Error: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate.

Tags: php, laravel, ssl, curl, woocommerce-rest-api

I am integrating Woo-commerce API's in my Laravel 5.6 site using Woo-commerce official rest sdk. I made a link using authentication endpoint URL.Which is mention at [here](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#rest-api-keys) .

When user clicks the link it takes the user to Woo-commerce authentication page, where user login and Approve the request.

After approving the request it should take me to return url which i mention in the link. 
Instead it shows me the following error.

Error: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50112424/curl-error-60-is-going-while-using-google-auth-api). But it's also not working.

I put the cacert.pem in '/etc/ssl/certs' directory, 
also make the entry in php.ini like

curl.cainfo = "/etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem". But it's not working.

Comment: after setting ssl cert in php.ini did you tried to restart apache server and then tested ?

Comment: You need to set your local SSL certificate and openssl, Check: https://www.tbs-certificates.co.uk/FAQ/en/openssl-windows.html

Comment: Yes i have restart apache.

Answer (score 0):

After investigation I found the solution. 
It does not work without ssl certificate.
I have install certificate using this [link](https://certbot.eff.org/) and it works.